How do I clean html code with multiple unwanted newlines using Python?
I have a lot of html pages that have somehow become embedded with multiple newline characters, with the tags on separate lines and some of the sentences split up at apparently random intervals.  Here is an example of what I am dealing with:
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>One of many</title>
        </head>
    <body>
        <h1>
    Spam is not ham
    </h1>
        <p>
    Many plates of Spam
    </p>
        <p>
    Use the Fry option to properly cook the
    Spam
    until done.
    </p>
        <p>
    Enquiries for more recipes can be made through the
    Feed Me
    option.
    </p>
      </body>
    </html>

I used the replace() function with partial success for the beginning tags with this code:
    html_filename = 'page.htm'

    f = open(html_filename, encoding="utf-8")
    file_str = f.readlines()
    f.close()

    with open(html_filename, 'w', encoding="utf-8") as f:
        for line in file_str:
            if '<h1>\n' in line:
                tmp = line.replace('<h1>\n', '<h1>')
                f.write(tmp)
            elif '<p>\n' in line:
                tmp = line.replace('<p>\n', '<p>')
                f.write(tmp)
            else:
                f.write(line)

and get the following result:
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>One of many</title>
        </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Spam is not ham
    </h1>
        <p>Many plates of Spam
    </p>
        <p>Use the Fry option to properly cook the
    Spam
    until done.
    </p>
        <p>Enquiries for more recipes can be made through the
    Feed Me
    option.
    </p>
      </body>
    </html>

However, I can't figure out how to resolve the lines with just text or the lines with just an end tag. I would like to end up with something like this:

<html>
    <head>
        <title>One of many</title>
    </head>
<body>
    <h1>Spam is not ham</h1>
    <p>Many plates of Spam</p>
    <p>Use the Fry option to properly cook the Spam until done.</p>
    <p>Enquiries for more recipes can be made through the Feed Me option.</p>
  </body>
</html>



maybe use lxml, or BeautifulSoup

maybe don't split into lines but get all text text = f.read() and search \n</ and replace it with </

You haven't said what the output should look like

The required output has not been stated. It appears that the main challenge is to merge lines that do not contain any XML/HTML tags.
You could use the standard/built-in xml.dom.minidom to both parse and prettify your data.
import xml.dom.minidom as MD

with open("foo.html", "r+", -1, "utf-8") as data:
    lines = []
    for line in map(str.strip, data):
        if line.startswith("<") or lines[-1].startswith("<"):
            lines.append(line)
        else:
            lines[-1] += " " + line
    pretty = MD.parseString("".join(lines)).toprettyxml("  ")
    start = pretty.index("<html>")
    data.seek(0)
    data.write(pretty[start:])
    data.truncate()

Output:
<html>
  <head>
    <title>One of many</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Spam is not ham</h1>
    <p>Many plates of Spam</p>
    <p>Use the Fry option to properly cook the Spam until done.</p>
    <p>Enquiries for more recipes can be made through the Feed Me option.</p>
  </body>
</html>


Thanks SIGHUP. This worked perfect the first time. However, when I ran it again I got the error, "if line.startswith("<") or lines[-1].startswith("<"): IndexError: list index out of range".

@mbrown1963 That's because your input data has a blank line before the first tag. The way you change the code in this answer will depend on how you want to process such blank lines - i.e., should they be included or excluded
